# Show that $\mathbb{F}_p[x,y]/\langle x^py-xy^p\rangle$ is not finitely generated over $\mathbb{F}_p[x-ay]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, finitely-generated

[The current bounty is for a specific answer which I can reward in 24 hours from now. Please ignore this bounty. An answer has been already given.]

> Let $p$ be a prime. Prove that $\forall a\in\mathbb{F}_p$ the algebra $\mathbb{F}_p[x,y]/\langle x^py-xy^p\rangle=:K$ is not finitely generated as a module over $F:=\mathbb{F}_p[x-ay]$.

**Attempt:**

Suppose the oposite. Then there's a surjective homomorphism $\phi:K\to F$. Thus $\exists f+I\in K, x-ay=\phi(f+I)$. Hence, (suppose for the moment that $p>2$),
$$
x^p-a^py^p=(x-ay)^p=\phi(f^p+I)
$$
where $$I=\langle x^py+xy^p\rangle$$
We can observe that $f^p\notin I$ because all the monoms in $f$ (as a polynomial in $x$ and as a polynomial in $y$) are from degree that is divided by $p$ which is impossible in the elements of $I$.

I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I'm confused. What's the module that $K$ is a submodule of? Also, how does $F$ live in that module?

Comment: If $K$ would be finite over $F$, then $x$ and $y$ would be integral over $F$. It would follow that $x^n$ and $y^m$ for some $n,m$ can be expressed by lower powers of $x$ and $y$, and thus that $K$ is finite dimensional as vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$. This is impossible since $K$ is one dimensional as a ring (Krull dimension). The point here seems to me merely that $x-ay$ is linear.

Comment: By $\mathbb{F}_p/\langle x^py-xy^p\rangle$, do you mean $\mathbb{F}_p\left[x,y\right] / \langle x^py-xy^p\rangle$ ? And "submodule by" means "submodule over"?

Answer (score 3):

First consider the ring automorphism $\varphi:\mathbb{F}_p[X,Y]\to \mathbb{F}_p[X,Y] $, $(X,Y)\mapsto (X+aY,Y)$. We observe $\varphi(X^pY-XY^p)=(X+aY)^pY-(X+aY)Y^p=X^pY-XY^p$ because of $a^p=a$ and $\varphi(\mathbb{F}_p[X-aY])=\mathbb{F}_p[X]$. Therefore we only need to show that $K:=\mathbb{F}_p[X,Y]/\left<X^pY-XY^p\right>$ isn't a finitely generated $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$-module. Because $K$ is finitely generated as $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$-algebra by $\overline{Y}$ this is equivalent to: $\overline{Y}$ isn't integral over $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$.

Let's assume $\overline{Y}$ is integral. Then there are $f_0,\ldots  f_n\in \mathbb{F}_p[X]$ such that $Y^{n+1} +f_nY^n+\cdots +f_0\in \left<X^pY-XY^p\right>\subset \left<XY\right>$. By canceling all mixed monomials we get $g(Y)+h(X)\in \left<XY\right>$ what is absurd.

Comment: There are two steps : using $(X,Y)\mapsto (X+aY,Y)\in Aut(\Bbb{F}_p[X,Y]/(X^pY-XY^p))$ and $(X^pY-XY^p)\subset (XY)$ it reduces to that $\Bbb{F}_p[X,Y]/(XY) =\Bbb{F}_p[X]+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty Y^n  \Bbb{F}_p$  isn't finitely generated $\Bbb{F}_p[X]$-module